# C# dynamic sitemap memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, sitemap

I have user control for my sitemap which has following in ascx:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath id="SiteMapPath1"runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" />
```

This sitemap control is called on each page of my website.

And the user control code behind:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ExpandForumPaths);
}
private SiteMapNode ExpandForumPaths(Object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
    SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;

    if (0 != postID)
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?PostID=" + postID.ToString();
    }

    if ((null != (tempNode = tempNode.ParentNode)) &&
        (0 != forumID))
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?ForumID=" + forumID.ToString();
    }

    if ((null != (tempNode = tempNode.ParentNode)) &&
        (0 != forumGroupID))
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?ForumGroupID=" + forumGroupID.ToString();
    }

    return currentNode;
}
```

The problem is that it is consuming 1 - 2 mb of ram per page load and is not releasing the memory back. For example, if I refresh the page 2 mb is added to w3wp.exe, it keeps growing.

```
   SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ExpandForumPaths);
```

I do believe the line above is causing the problem by creating a new eventhandler every time my user control is used.

**Question** This method for making dynamic sitemap has failed. Is there any other way to do it without consuming memory, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `SiteMap.SiteMapResolve -= this.ExpandForumPaths` on the page Unload event? The `SiteMap.SiteMapResolve` is static, therefore handlers keep piling up in there for each page load.

Comment: @thecoon, sorry for late response, yes I did SiteMap.SiteMapResolve -= this.ExpandForumPaths; but it has no effect, but if I do force GC.Collect(); on unload the w3wp.exe process stop consuming memory.

Comment: @AI25 If that is indeed the case (no memory growth on forced GC.Collect() calls), that means there is no memory leak,  rather just the process choosing to consume new resources rather than reuse existing resources.  When the operating system requests cleanup (causing an automatic garbage collection), your memory should be returned.  Have you found this is not the case?

Comment: @JTorres if I disable this sitemap, compile and upload the dll on production it does not goes above 55 MB, the problem is the traffic 1000 page hits per day, and more over their are other application running on the server and just I have 1 gb of free memory on the server, the strange thing is that when the process reaches 200 - 300 mb, GC cleans my cache, also I have 2mb cache in this application that i keep for 24 hours, meaning that it will expire only when 24 hour are complete, so GC is cleaning my cache but not the static  sitemap event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/04/sitemapresolve-and-dynamic-site-map.html

According to the article above, on every Page_Load a new SiteMapResolveEventHandler is added because SiteMapResolve is static, seems a good reason for unnecessary excessive memory allocation. Article also has a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep your sitemap in one static cache and only store the current node id(s) against the user. 1-2mb of RAM suggests you are building a sitemap per user (let alone per request) which seems overkill.

Something like

```
var nodes = Session["ExpandedNodes"] as List<integer>
AddCurrentPageToExpandedNodes(nodes)
var siteMapForUser = StaticSiteMap.Apply(nodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about removing the handler as well with this line of code

```
SiteMap.SiteMapResolve -= this.ExpandForumPaths
```